# Table of content with chapters displayed like sections

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, rendering

I try to get a rendering for chapters in the TOC inside the `book` class like if they was sections with no bold font and no breaking line after each chapter.
My goal is to get a rendering like this for the chapters:

[image]

So, I made the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {}% <above-code>
  {\thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

But when I compile it, I get a kind of horizontal ugly rendering:
[image]

So how can I get normal vertical rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I get it, the following code is the solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]
  {}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel \hfill]{1.5em}\hspace*{0em}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[0.8pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\section{test} \lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]

\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```